# Como imprimo una pagina a tamaño Carta HTML?

Tags: php, html, css, imprimir

Buen dia, estoy generando un documento con una consulta en PHP y todo funciona de maravilla; he aplicado un estilo CSS y logre colocar una imagen membrete, ahora bien puse un botón para imprimir pero cunado carga la vista previa la imagen vs el texto de la consulta no queda del todo centrado y se ve mal al imprimir pues sale desfasada la imagen y el texto super pequeño. Como podría generar esa impresión a tamaño carta?

CSS:

```
body,td,th {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px
}

p { font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%}
h4 {font-size: 150%;}
@media print {
body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}
}

body {
    background-image: url(bgcert1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 816px 1000px;
    zoom: 100%;
@page { 
    size: 816px 1056px;
    margin: 10%;
}
}
@media print{
.ocultar-al-imprimir { display:none; }
}
```

imagen de referencia:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GhGimti2qBiNRkzBzXttHWDbEPO84CCp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Prueba poniendo dentro de `@media print { body { ` un width de `width: 898px;`... A mi me funcionó en un caso que tuve a ver si te va bien a ti.  Si sigue viendose pequeño comprueba que no hay nada que sobrepase esa anchura. Si aún asi sigue pequeño y lo haces con tablas, ponles un width de 100% a ellas. (aunque aqui usamos a4, quizas en tu caso deba ser un poco mas ancho si usas letter)

Comment: En cuanto a pegar enlaces a google drive para insertar imagenes en la pregunta, te recomiendo que peges directamente la imagen usando el boton de imagen mientras estas editando la pregunta.  No hace falta que la tengas previamente guardada, solo copiada en memoria, y seleccionas el enlace **pega** y en el siguiente input que aparece tan solo pega sin escribir nada y veras que la imagen queda insertada

Answer (score 0):

Trata de configurar este css

```
@media print {

  introducir el código aquíhtml, body {
    height:100%; 
    margin: 0 !important; 
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

}
```